# WebBrowser does not expect the page loads on Yandex

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

```
public partial class WebBrowserForm : Form
{
    public WebBrowserForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser.Navigate("http://ya.ru");
    }
    private void PlayButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    _documentCompleted = false;
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += BrowserDocumentCompleted;
    var input = webBrowser.Document.All
        .Cast<HtmlElement>()
        .Where(elem => elem.GetAttribute("id") == "text")
        .First();

    input.Focus();
    SendKeys.SendWait("mercedes");
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");

    while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete || !_documentCompleted)
        Application.DoEvents();

    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= BrowserDocumentCompleted;

    return; // (!!!)
}

void BrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _documentCompleted = true;
}
private bool _documentCompleted;
}
```

I have the following situation. Button on the form above tries to enter a query in the search engine Yandex request Mercedes, activate search (press enter) and analyze html code that will return a search engine. The problem is that if you put a breakpoint in the code with a comment (!!!), Then at a given point in the webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml html code is not stored the search results. I tried different browser events in vain.
[c-sharp-webbrowser-button-click-then-go-to-another-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904091/c-sharp-webbrowser-button-click-then-go-to-another-page) This link has a similar problem, but not realized in my case.

Framework 4.0 VS2010 Windows 7 Ultimate x64 IE9.0. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you use webbrowser control only to get responce text from yandex search?

Comment: I need to parse the search results Yandex in html, using internal webBrowser's parser.